# Plot a table of functions with different color

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have a function with two independent variables:

```
SNR[t_, f_] := 20 Log10[1/(2 Pi f t)]
```

And I have a list for "t"

```
tlist = {0.1*10^-12, 1*10^-12, 10*10^-12, 100*10^-12, 1*10^-9};
```

Then I use the code below to plot the functions:

```
LogLinearPlot[Table[SNR[t, f], {t, tlist}], {f, 1*10^6, 100*10^6}, Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, FrameLabel -> {"f(Hz)", "SNR(dB)"}, PlotLabel -> "SNR vs f for Different Jitter Values"]
```

The lines are plotted, but all the lines are in the same color. Is there a method to make the lines are drawn with different colors?

Comment: You should add `Evaluate` before table

Comment: You mean that I need put the `Table[]` into `Evaluate[]`? I do it, but warnings are popped out.

Comment: Yes, thats it. What kind of warnings?

Comment: Table::iterb: "Iterator {t,tlist} does not have appropriate bounds."

Comment: Just to be sure, does this example raise error too or not: `LogLinearPlot[Evaluate@Table[SNR[t, f], {t, tlist}], {f, 1*10^6, 100*10^6}]`

Comment: @funnypony: Thanks, both `Table[]` and `Table@` works now.

Comment: @Karsten7: Your link is helpful too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works

```
SNR[t_, f_] := 20 Log10[1/(2 Pi f t)]
tlist = {0.1*10^-12, 1*10^-12, 10*10^-12, 100*10^-12, 1*10^-9};
LogLinearPlot[Evaluate@Table[SNR[t, f], {t, tlist}], {f, 1*10^6, 100*10^6},  Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic,  FrameLabel -> {"f(Hz)", "SNR(dB)"}, PlotLabel -> "SNR vs f for Different Jitter Values"]
```

Check Wolfram announcement on `PlotThemes` [here](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/plot-themes/labels-colors-and-plot-markers.html)